# Copying all sheets from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have an XLTM Template and an xlsx workbook.

The XLSX workbook has around 300-400 sheets.

I am looking to copy sheets from XLSX to XLSM Template.

What is the fastest way to do it?

I would like to have the same **sheet name and formats along with the values**.

Here is a copy of the code that I am using,

```
For k = 1 To xlWkb.Worksheets.Count
    xlWkb.Activate
    xlWkb.Sheets(k).Select
    xlWkb.Sheets(k).Cells.Copy

    xlWkb2.Activate
    xlWkb2.Sheets("Sheet" & k).Select
    xlWkb2.Sheets("Sheet" & k).Range("A1").Select
    xlWkb2.ActiveSheet.Paste ' changes the column width and all, I want those formats

    xlWkb2.Sheets("Sheet" & k).Name = xlWkb.Sheets(k).Name
Next
```

Comment: If the xltm file didn't already have sheets with the same names, you could simply use `xlWkb.Worksheets.Copy After:=xlWkb2.Worksheets(1)` - no need for a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, remove the lines that have `Activate` and `Select` on them and restructure it more like this:

```
For k = 1 To xlWkb.Worksheets.Count
    xlWkb.WorkSheets(k).Cells.Copy
    xlWkb2.WorkSheets("Sheet" & k).Range("A1").Paste 
    xlWkb2.WorkSheets("Sheet" & k).Name = xlWkb.WorkSheets(k).Name
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, find next [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-copy-method-excel)

```
Sheets("SheetName").Copy Before:=Workbooks("WorkbookName").Sheets(1)
Workbooks("WorkbookName").Sheets(1).Name = Sheets("SheetName").Name
```

This method Copy entire Worksheet with formatting, range names, values, formulas.. etc.